# this works for me but need it to do mp4 and avi as well

Tags: php, html, mp4, avi

The code below works for me in image files what would i need to add to get it to display .avi and .mp4 files as well.

```
   <?php
 $files = glob("images/*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
  {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
     );

     $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
     if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo basename($image)."<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
         echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
        } else {
            continue;
        }
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: Use the video tag for mp4, and avi simply will not work in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

`.avi` and `.mp4` files are videos, not images, so you should output a `<video>` tag for them:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
  {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png',
            'avi',
            'mp4',
     );

     $videos = [ 'avi', 'mp4' ];

     $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
     if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
       echo basename($image)."<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";

       if ( in_array( $ext, $videos )) {
         echo '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="' . $image . '" type="video/mp4"></video>';
       } else {
         echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
       }

     } else {
       continue;
     }
  }
?>
```

More information on the `<video>` tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp